# C# XNA 2D Collision Detection with push back?

Tags: c#

Does anyone know of any good tutorials that cover collision detection with the push back effect, where when 2 objects collide they are pushed back to their separate ways?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to reverse the direction when a collision occurs, this can be done via:

```
Direction.X *= -1;
```

And then assigning:

`Position += Direction;`

A simple google search will provide plenty of results on this.

Answer (score -1):

I really enjoyed [Asteroid Belt Assault](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781849690669/asteroid-belt-assault-lost-in-space/ch04#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE4NDk2OTA2NjkvY2gwNGx2bDFzZWMyMQ==) (you'll have to sign up or do a trial). Asteroids bounce off each other in a very realistic way.

Comment: This was more like what I was looking for. Thank you. Luckily I found the book on TPB.